# how to return value when using linq query to select multiple columns from joined table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2` as following:-

```
Table1
| ServiceNumber | Name | Appointment | Department | DateofJoining|
```

and

```
Table2
|ServiceNumber | Age | Sex | SpouseName| NumberOfChildren |
```

now i've a following LINQ Query

```
var result = from p in Table1
             join p in Table2 
             on p.ServiceNumber equals q.ServiceNumber
             select new {
                p.ServiceNumber,
                q.Name,
                q.SpouseName
             };
```

This is written inside a function `returnSpouseDetails()`. My problem is what is going to be the return type of this function. Since the returned result is not of the type of either tables(classes). Should I write another class just to return this value or there is a better method?

Comment: Yes, you could create a new type that holds these informations like `SpouseDetail`.

Comment: you have used dynamic Return type

Comment: in case used generic class

Comment: You can create a different class as you mentioned or else can return Tuple<string, string, string> if you don't wanna create separate class.

Comment: @SAJ your comment guided me in the right direction. Please submit it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a different class as you mentioned or else can return Tuple if you don't wanna create separate class.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx is the official link about Tuple.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no better way.  The code that receives that return value of that function has no way of knowing what the properties of that object are, unless they're defined in a class somewhere.